# Why is the number of elements in a group called "order"?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, terminology

This is a question that I have for a long time, Why is the number of elements in a group called "order"? I mean, the word "order" in Spanish (which is my language) has a very strong meaning in terms of "ordering", but it does not refer to quantities. What was the motivation for this?

Comment: Likely it arose from the early study of permutation groups, viz. the order of a permutation,  probably dating back to the early work of Cauchy anrd Jordan,  where they discovered the special case of Lagrange's theorem for a subgroup generated by a single element (for the case of permutation groups).

Comment: The OED's earliest cite for *order* as the number of elements in a group: "1878   A. Cayley in *Amer. Jrnl. Math.* 1 51   A set of symbols α, β, γ..such that the product αβ of each two of them..is a symbol of the set, is a group... When the number of the symbols (or terms) is = n, then the group is of the nth order." Their earliest cite for the order of an element of a group is from Burnside in 1897.

Comment: I assume it came from the order of its underlying set, so maybe the question is where that came from.

Comment: Someone has closed the question and I think the answer given does not answer mine. As such, they say nothing about what was the motivation

Comment: @Hopmaths The answer in the linked dupe *does* explain the motivation -  same as in the above comments. Why do you think it does not?

Comment: @bill:   I think OP is asking why the word order, which refers to which element comes first, is used for the total number of elements

Comment: I cast the final reopen vote as the other question is asking specifically for the connecting between "order of an element" and "order of a group", while this question is asking about the origin of the term. However, maybe the [History of Science and Mathematics](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/) stack exchange might be a better place to ask this question (especially if answers are going to offer unsourced history here, as with the answer to the other question!).

Comment: The word "order" *also* has a strong connotation of ordering in English; Spanish is not alone in that respect.

Comment: @user1729 May I then ask the same question there?

Comment: @Hopmaths Yes. Maybe either delete this one here, or link back from there to here (so the folk there know you asked here first and it was suggested you ask there).

Comment: Based on other examples of "order", the fact that it comes from Latin from "series, line, row", and the OED citation, there's a slight possibility it indirectly comes from group multiplication tables.  More likely is from thinking about a classification of groups, where the nth order of group is one with n elements.

Comment: The question on the History and Science and Maths site is [here](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/13337/9504).

Answer (score 4):

I [answered](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/a/13425/9504) this question on hsm.SE. As the question here is still open and lying in the "unanswered questions" queue, I've made this Community Wiki answer which duplicates my answer from hsm.SE.

---

The theory of permutations and permutation groups was the original (abstract) setting of group theory, and so the term originated there. I believe the reason for it was as follows:

> The order of a permutation is the least number such that the ordering of the index set is preserved.

I looked in both Lagrange's [1771 memoir](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=_-U_AAAAYAAJ&pg=PA138&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) and Cauchy's [1844 memoir](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=-c3fxufDQVEC&pg=PA151#v=onepage&q&f=false), which both address [Lagrange's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_(group_theory)) on orders of subgroups. Lagrange barely uses the word order (well, "ordre" as he is writing in French), and doesn't use it in a way which influences our discussion here (the only relevant use is on p201, when he changes the orders of variables in an equation).

Cauchy's memoir is more relevant. He goes from talking about, basically, "permutations change the order of the index set" to defining the order of a permutation. He doesn't justify this name, but writing like this does suggest the reason is that it is the least number such that the ordering of the index set is preserved, as per my claim above.